# How to create an object automatically (e.g. in a loop)

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program where some kind of action in the could automatically creates an Object.

[[image: I know that this could not work but it demonstrates what I need]]

Can anybody help me and tell me how to implement this so that it could work?
Thanks alot

Comment: Please post your code as text, not image, see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Interesting syntax. Is that Python 4? Also, what has this got to do with UML??

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to dynamically create var names, you could however
conditianally fill a list with your created Object and access using index or fill a dictionary, pass a key and as value give the object.

```
some_dict = {}
for i in range(10):
    some_dict[i] = newObject()
```